# Safe to distribute work of a normal function to multiple threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, thread-safety, memory-model

Is it in general safe to distribute the work of a function on different threads, to perform work in parallel, as long as no user call back is run in ways surprising to the user?

The assumption here is that either no user call back is passed to the function, or call backs are always run in the "main" thread (the one of that function).

The issue is a function that doesn't document any threading or relation with threads and historically was not thread based; can such function decide to run code in different threads without breaking any possible user call?

In any case the function would wait until all threads (or work units sent to a worker thread) have finished dealing with the data before returning, obviously.

Comment: That is a very broad question and the answer is always with such: It depends. If you have shared  data it gets ugly and so on. If you have a specific question in mind than please ask that one. That makes it easier to answer in a meaningful way.

Comment: @n314159 It isn't "broad". It's safe or it isn't. I want to know if there exist cases which don't allow it, as I don't see any.

Comment: If the function is thread-safe, then it's safe; if it's not thread-safe, then it's not.  I'm not sure what more can be said than that.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Yes but will a called function be less thread safe than a "main" function?

Comment: @curiousguy sure, it could be -- for example, the called function might get or a set a static or global variable without synchronization, which would introduce a race condition if it is called from multiple threads.  It just depends on how the function is implemented.

Comment: I agree with @n314159 that this question is perhaps too broad - the answer will depend on the specific purpose and use case of the function. Some functions are thread safe and others are not; without seeing the implementation there's really no way to know for sure.

Comment: Designing thread-safe algorithms is always tricky. Clearly, it's possible, but you have to be sure that the problem you're splitting is suitable for splitting. That makes it's very, very problem dependent.

Comment: @JosephLarson It's difficult but is it transparent for the calling function?

Answer (score 2):

In general it is not safe.  There are plenty of non thread safe functions out there and you can't assume the function you are getting does not use them.

You need to tell the user that the function will be parallelized so that they can know that the function they pass to you needs to be thread safe.

Comment: Yes I understand that user call back may not always safely be called in another thread but what if there are no call backs?

Comment: @curiousguy It's still not safe.  If for example the user's code calls [`gmtime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/gmtime) then you could have a data race.

Comment: @curiousguy i dont understand why you focus so much on callbacks, there are plenty of things that break when you do them in parallel. As Nathan said, if it is not stated explicitly you should assume a function is not thread safe

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica Why would anyone use ancient functions like `gmtime`?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I simply assume that any sanely written code using sane primitives is "thread safe".

Comment: @curiousguy thats a rather daring premise. I cannot use such assumption

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 When is good code not thread safe?

Comment: @curiousguy note that before c++11 the notion of "thread safe" didnt even exist in c++

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 People have been documenting "thread safe" functions for decades before.

Comment: @curiousguy "When is good code not thread safe?" when it was not written to target threadsafety. Often you have to add overhead to get it, and this is not always desirable. Anyhow I dont want to spam this answer more ;)

Comment: @curiousguy Updating code bases is expensive.  It'll take a long while before a lot of the old C++98/03 code is gone.  I'm just trying to example that there are functions in the standard that explicitly say they aren't thread safe so in general you can't assume that all functions are.  Anything that has state may be not thread safe.

Comment: @curiousguy just one last thing, "have been documenting "thread safe" functions for decades before" and they documented it because in general you cannot safely assume threadsafety ;)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I don't see how any reasonable C++ pre-thread code would not be thread safe.

Comment: @curiousguy Nathan already mentioned `gmtime`. It already caused me troubles in a real scenario. I can well imagine that there are many functions that have very similar problem, especially anything that uses `errno` or similar mechanism. Tbh I dont know what you are arguing for. I know from experience that it is not safe to assume anything is thread safe, you claim otherwise, I cannot convince you, so what?

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica But I don't see why C++98/03 code that was sanely written with sane primitives would not be thread safe. The cases must have been quite rare.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Does anyone consider that a function F that uses static storage to return a value has a sane interface? It's usually not thread safe (though F could trivially be made thread safe), but F isn't async signal safe either (even for functions that have no other reasons to cause issues in a signal), you can use it more than once in an expression only in modern C++ (so the old/new code issue is the opposite of what you say), it's an incitement to keep a pointer too long and invalidate it...

Comment: @curiousguy see for example [30.2.3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf): "Concurrent access to a stream object (30.8, 30.9), stream buffer object (30.6), or C Library stream (30.12) bymultiple threads may result in a data race (6.8.2) unless otherwise specified (30.4)" Even using `std::cout` is not thread safe. This was just the first random thing I found in the standard

Comment: ... all functions X need to document whether they might call F for internal purpose if you intend to call X in the same expression as F, which is ugly and very unlikely to be documented, so in practice **it's extremely likely that a lot of code would depend on non guaranteed but probably correct assumptions.** So who wants to defend that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202824/discussion-between-curiousguy-and-formerlyknownas-463035818).